# How should I structure my namespace tree so that I have a Math class and Math namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I don't know if this is a good or bad idea, or if it's technically even possible... but I'd like to have something of the following sort:

```
public class Math {
  public int gcd(a,b) // Method for Greatest Common Denominator
  public int lcm(a,b) // Method for Least Common Multiple
  public int factorial(a) // Method for factorial
  ...
}
```

and then I'd also like to have a namespace called `Math` that has subclasses such as `Math.Matrix`, `Math.RowVector`, `Math.ColumnVector`, etc... so I can define my own Matrix data structure and its associated actions.

Is this advisable? I am not too keen on the idea of using some other name for my `Math` class, as I want it to be a static class with all sorts of functions/methods that are useful to me, and at the same time, I want to gather all my relevant data structures under a `Math` namespace.

Comment: You could use the `Math` class as a namespace itself. I mean, if everything is static, then you can define inner classes inside `Math`. Can't you? As for the namespace whatever you like most, you won't be arranging many things inside, only one class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See these for a clarification: [Do not name a class the same as its namespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20151122031318/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx) and [Names of Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces)

Basically,

> DO NOT use the same name for a namespace and a type in that namespace.

I would use something like `MathUtilities` or `MathUtil`, for short, for the namespace and then you can have your `MathUtil.Math` and the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Is it technically possible?  Try it and find out, at worst the compiler will yell at you, but won't call you nasty names.

What you are trying to do is make a "Utils" or similar class that should be in your Math namespace.  Generally though "Utils" class is frowned upon but still well understood if you use it.  In that case you can break them up into disciplines like Math.Trig or Math.Geometry.